# Eclipse with pydev cant import theano

Tags: eclipse, pydev, theano

I have installed theano. ipython detects theano, however eclipse fails to do so. i have installed pydev & normal python cods using numpy work fine.

i have set theanorc as follows:

```
[cuda]
/usr/local/cuda-7.0

[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
```

what settings do i have to do to allow pydev detect theano?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Answer (score 0):

After installing Theano when I restarted eclipse, it automatically displayed a popup asking my permission to add theano to PYTHONPATH. I have installed theano and eclipse in both Windows and Linux PC and both are working fine.

My steps are as follows:

1. Install Anaconda (Python distribution from Continuum Analytics)
2. Setup Eclipse to use it ([link](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm))
3. In terminal (cmd for Windows) execute following two commands:

   a) pip install Theano

   b) conda install pydot-ng
4. Start/Restart eclipse and it will automatically dispay the popup asking your permission to add Theano to PYTHONPATH.